# Add numbers in a list using recursion in Python

Tags: python, recursion

The given template is:

```
def total(lst):
    return (
        #### YOUR CODE HERE ####
        #### DO NOT WRITE CODE OUTSIDE OF THIS ####
        #### RETURN STATEMENT ####
    )

def getValue():    
    try:
        return int(input())
    except:
        return None        

v = getValue()
myLst = [v]
while v != None:    
    v = getValue()
    if v != None:
        myLst.append(v)
print(total(myLst))
```

I have gotten this:

```
def total(lst):
    return (
        if lst ==1:
            lst[0]
        else:
            lst[0]+total(lst[0:])
    )

def getValue():    
    try:
        return int(input())
    except:
        return None        

v = getValue()
myLst = [v]
while v != None:    
    v = getValue()
    if v != None:
        myLst.append(v)
print(total(myLst))
```

The input is:
1
2
3
4
5
It should print the sum of all the numbers.
But this gives me an error:

```
  File "main.py", line 3
    if lst ==1:
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help me figure out what I did wrong! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're only allowed to write code inside an expression, you need to use a slightly different syntax for `if`-statements.

```
if len(lst) == 1:
    lst[0]
else:
    lst[0]+total(lst[0:])
```

can be written as a single statement as:

```
lst[0] if len(lst) == 1 else lst[0]+total(lst[0:])
```

(assuming you wanted to check the length of the list, rather than doing a compare against an int, which is always going to be false)

Comment: Thank you. This helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You put an if *statement* inside a return *expression*. Putting a statement inside an expression is a syntax error. Use an if expression instead, such as

```
return (
    lst[0] if lst == 1 else lst[0] + total(lst[0:])
)
```